Kotlin AES GCM Tag mismatch
I have a problem with Kotlin AES GCM encryption. while decrypting, the key,iv,tag and data comes from third party API and on their JavaScript documentation the process is like the following code :
 for (var i = 0; i < validations.length; i++) {
  var decipher = forge.cipher.createDecipher("AES-GCM", sessionKey);
  decipher.start({
    iv: atob(validations[i].iv),
    tag: atob(validations[i].tag),
  });

  decipher.update(forge.util.createBuffer(atob(validations[i].data)));
  var pass = decipher.finish();

  if (pass) {
    dec_validations.push({
      data: btoa(decipher.output.data),
      id: validations[i].id,
    });
  }
}

my Kotlin code is like this :
fun main() {
val myTestKey = "22+uMvw39JLTXeBJweORNRQPeVneGP0+oQgvwmjSx4Y="
val iv = "+7/pEeTMDH8uyShG"
val tag = "3sSY6JEEY8EdXMmrnhgN3Q=="
val cipherText = "jzgiE5bec+ty0xI3zhsXZVbCuUwSttOBpuH2Ts0R/CLVh9Vf4rw2HM7ZRWizXcQ1SElurXdNNFRyfXMF8N/WUjjPgaUAV9dvtB8wfDqkq5rsbvpUIi8OAVXvAa/rwhMZgfTcIOUbB2q3A+tft3T+K4aBSOTl1a8btmjMmlZ+lFYIXWLBSu0L9As6gAkSUkCWOQMs7Up9guOnP9r6E/lhO1gQnuPkebiKjJWkVYM+Ezwgnne0b4P6dD59aPc03eqxmMRdxk5/SSbPLysj2pHprsD01zH401KsID+Ny5sJDS1gvXz8eegTySriKEIpMn8nUkK5yKru4aEgGFcz0amSlK1dmqmAdL6ZOPcT3EAcobY="
val decodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(myTestKey)
val sessionKeySpec: Key = SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, "AES")

val ivBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(iv)
val tagBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(tag)
val gcmSpec: AlgorithmParameterSpec = GCMParameterSpec(128, ivBytes)
val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding")

cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sessionKeySpec, gcmSpec)

val ciphertext = Base64.getDecoder().decode(cipherText)
val combined = ByteBuffer.allocate(ciphertext.size + tagBytes.size)
    .put(ciphertext)
    .put(tagBytes)
    .array()

val plaintext = cipher.doFinal(combined)

println(String(plaintext))
}

what i have tried :

adding cipher.updateAAD(tagBytes).
Concatenate tagByte and data together.


...Concatenate tagByte and data together... The data must be concatenated in the order ciphertext|tag. But whether this is really the issue is unclear, as the posted Kotlin code does not contain the concatenation.

I can't reproduce the problem with my own test data and the correct order ciphertext|tag. Please post a complete, executable code and complete non-productive sample data for a repro.

As is you should first decode the data, then decode the tag and then use update for the data and doFinal for the tag (for instance). No need to concatenate, the buffering is already within the Cipher. Maybe you were concatenating the base 64?

Sure, you can use the update()/doFinal() approach, but unlike Java, Kotlin uses the + operator for concatenation: cipher.doFinal(ciphertext + tag).

Thank you for the effort! i edited the question i post a clearer code (i hope). normally these data comes from third-party API and i should to decrypt it to do what i want.

Your data is still inconsistent. The new data posted with the Kotlin code cannot be decrypted even with the Node Forge reference code: https://jsfiddle.net/7y681eoc/2/! The decryption only works if the encrypted data (cipherText) is interpreted as the concatenation of ciphertext and tag (see answer): https://jsfiddle.net/nj7a14me/2/, which makes it unclear what the posted tag (3sSY6JEEY8EdXMmrnhgN3Q==) is supposed to be. You should agree the conventions used with the third-party provider. This isn't actually an encryption issue, but a communication issue between the parties involved.

There is some confusion with your data. It appears that the variable cipherText already includes the AES-GCM authentication tag appended to the end. I am not sure what the variable tag contains, but if I change the second-to-last line to val plaintext = cipher.doFinal(ciphertext) (i.e. exclude tagBytes) then decryption succeeds.
